# Is it possible to disable a single default feature in Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

From reading [this page](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html), it states that you need to turn off all defaults to override them.

> With the exception of the `default` feature, all features are opt-in. To opt out of the default feature, use `default-features = false` and cherry-pick individual features.

Other build systems I've used (CMake, SCons, Autotools, Jam) all allow to change a single default.

Is this possible with Cargo?

---

*This is useful because in most cases I want to use default options, with only minor adjustments.
Its also important to me that in the future - new features which the developers think should be enabled by default, are not disabled on my build because I chose to adjust an unrelated feature.*

Edit: [opened issue regarding this feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3126).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but your motivation sounds reasonable. Ideas for improvements to Cargo can be submitted as [GitHub issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues) or (for more major things than this) [RFCs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs).

Answer (score 11):

Currently, No. You have to disable all "default" features, then opt back in for the ones you want. So you have to know what the "default" list is, and opt-back-in for all but the one you want to omit.

This [GH issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3126) describes the status and discusses possibilities, but remains open (3y later).